# How to copy a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, xcode, copy, nsmutablearray, deep-copy

I would simply like to know how to copy a NSMutableArray so that when I change the array, my reference to it doesn't change. How can I copy an array?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do so:

```
NSArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:oldArray];

NSArray *newArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray] autorelease];

NSArray *newArray = [[oldArray mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

These will all create **shallow copies**, though.

(**Edit:** If you're working with ARC, just delete the calls to `autorelease`.)

For **deep copies** use this instead:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray copyItems:YES] autorelease];
```

**Worth noting:** For obvious reasons the latter will require all your array's element objects to implement `NSCopying`.

Comment: What do you mean by shallow and deep copies??

Comment: @Supertecnoboff: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. I never knew about this concepts.

Comment: A shallow copy is a new array that contains references to the same elements, a deep copy is a new array that contains copies of each element.
If you made a shallow copy and then changed one of the elements in the original array, the shallow copy would also show this change. If it was a deep copy it would not.

Comment: [sourceArray mutableCopy] with iOS 10 is working great